# How to monitor the Internet connectivity on two PCs simultaneously?

Tags: python, http, cron, connection, monitor

I have two PCs and I want to monitor the Internet connectivity in both of them and make it available in a page as to whether they're currently online and running. How can I do that?

I'm thinking of a cron job that gets executed every minute that sends a POST to a file located in a server, which in turn would write the connectivity status "online" to a file. In the page where the statuses are displayed, read from both the status files and display whether they're online or not. But this feels like a sloppy idea. What alternative suggestion do you have?

(The answer doesn't necessarily have to be code; I'm not looking for copy-paste solutions. I just want an idea, a nudge in the right directio,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just a GET request (you just need a ping to indicate that the PC is on) sent periodically to maybe a Django server and if you query a page on the Django server, it shows a webpage indicating the status of each.

In the Django server have a loop where the time each GET is received is indicated, if the time between the last GET and current time is too large, set a flag to false.

That flag will later be visible when the URL is queried, via the views.

I don't think this would end up sloppy, just a trivial solution where you don't really have to dig too deep to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Nagios in the past I like it a lot. It is free and open source. I have used it to monitor several Web, DNS, Mail servers and a proxy.  You can check it here: https://www.nagios.com/products/nagioscore